# 3d Cloud Morphing

Tags: cloud, morphing

I would like to know how to do cloud morphing. For example, morph the cloud from a random type into some shape such as pen or dog.

Don't know how to search this properly using keyboards. Would appreciate if anyone can guide me some directions.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "cloud morphing"? Take a white fluffy sky-cloud and play balloon animals with it, do that in graphics, or something involving cloud computing?

Comment: I would like to take a white fluffy sky-cloud and play balloon animals with it :) If you figure out how to do it in graphics i will be very interested...

Comment: If you can use a 3D points cloud (like those generated by the Kinect camera, for example) or an array of vertices for your two shapes you can simply interpolate the position of each point (x-y-z or vector), starting from 0 (first shape) to 1 (second shape). If you want to make it simple, the number of points should be the same. Otherwise is a bit more tricky, but you can probably figure it out. :)